# Problem with TableView in Swift (only empty Rows)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I got a problem with my tableview. It is a tableview in a normal ViewController.

This is my ViewController:

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


var tableView:UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")

    view.addSubview(tableView)


    var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide!
    layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true



    tableView.reloadData()


}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    12
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

}

[This is my PostTableViewCell.**xib**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kshaM.jpg)

My PostTableViewCell.**swift** is empty.

This is my result:
[Iphone View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIkIS.jpg)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both function are specting a int return and toy are only using a number

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 12
}

Comment: What is the problem with this?

Comment: The missing return in the datasource methods

Comment: You are not returning just set a number but the function is espected to return an int value

Comment: Since Swift 5, `return` keyword can be omitted in single line methods.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution. Just added the rowHeight